# Headers already sent - characters after ?> in every single file (thousands) - is there a way to quickly delete the extra characters?

Tags: php, notepad++, carriage-return

As in the title, I have thousands of files (UTF-8) which for some reason have inherited two carriage returns after the end of the PHP code. This is causing "header already sent" errors in my program.

I have tried finding/replacing with Notepad++ but I don't know how to define a carriage space. Is there any way I can use a program to go through each file and replace:

"?>

"

with:

"?>"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use notepad++ Search & Replace function to do this? You have to select your "find" and copy it and paste it in notepad++, it will let you paste multi-line text.

Comment: If your files are saved with Unix line endings, then `\n` else `\r\n` is your line ending; and can be used in extended mode in Notepad++ Find/Replace

Comment: In the future, if there's no output after the closing PHP tag, you may omit it.

Comment: @user3536141 consider accepting an Answer in order to **a)** mark this question as answered (*thus preventing it from getting more unneeded attention*) and **b)** to appretiate the effort of the people writing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:

Select your "Find" text like this:

[image]

Step 2: Press **CTRL + H** and enter your replacement text:

[image]

Step 3: Press **Replace All** button:

[image]

As you can see, it does work. You can use the "Find in Files" to batch this operation also against many files, without having to do one by one manually.

Answer (score 0):

Err, this is not really a coding question and will probably be closed soon, but nevertheless here's how you do it:

1. On Notepad++, press **Ctrl+F**
2. Select the **Replace** tab
3. Under **Search mode** check the radio button: **Extended (\n,\r,\t...)**
4. Search for string `"<?\r\n\r\n"` and replace with `"?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `"?>\R+"`
Replace with: `"?>"`

Select `Regular expression` and click on `Replace All`

`\R` stands for any of `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`.